# Unhandled exception at 0x5401FA96 (sfml-system-d-2.dll)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I am trying to make a simple program with SFML. The source code is the same provided in this [example](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/window-opengl.php)

Given that I downloaded SFML from the site using the precompiled version from Visual Studio 12.

I configured the project normally, and added the correct libraries for debug and release.

#### Note:

There were no compiler errors, and not linker errors as well. I also added the .dll libraries in the .exe directory.

When I run the program, here is the output (just crashes):

```
Exception thrown at 0x50FAFA96 (sfml-system-d-2.dll) in TestSFML.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCD8.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

From what I looked on the internet, this error seems to be related to mixing debug and release libraries, but I think I did it right.

Note that I am using **Visual Studio Community 2015**, but I don't think this could cause the problem.

#### The configuration inside the project

**Release and Debug (All Configurations)**:

Added the same directory for the include path (release and debug) and library path (release and debug).

**Release**

On `Linker -> Input` I added:

```
sfml-window.lib
sfml-system.lib
```

**Debug**

On `Linker->Input` I added:

```
sfml-system-d.lib
sfml-window-d.lib
```

Since I am using dynamic libraries, I also added the libraries on the directory of the executable.

#### EDIT

Main.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>

int main()
{
    // create the window
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "OpenGL", sf::Style::Default, sf::ContextSettings(32));
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    // load resources, initialize the OpenGL states, ...

    // run the main loop
    bool running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        // handle events
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                // end the program
                running = false;
            }
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::Resized)
            {
                // adjust the viewport when the window is resized
                glViewport(0, 0, event.size.width, event.size.height);
            }
        }

        // clear the buffers
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // draw...

        // end the current frame (internally swaps the front and back buffers)
        window.display();
    }

    // release resources...

    return 0;
}
```

Aditional dependencies on the project. They were set on `Active(Debug)`

```
opengl32.lib
sfml-system-d.lib
sfml-window-d.lib
```

The compilation

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestSFML, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>  TestSFML.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Leonardo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestSFML\x64\Debug\TestSFML.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're linking as static/dynamic?

Comment: Also, are you using `int main()`?

Comment: using int main, I just copied the example from the site

Comment: I think that I am linking as dynamic, since I Visual Studio asks me to put the .dll files with the executable

Comment: Give us the compilation options. Did you link with OpenGL? Give us the command line options you gave as well as the `main.cpp` file if you can.

Comment: Don't mix Visual Studio versions. Downgrade to 2012, build SFML for 2015, or check if you can change the compiler to 2012 in the project settings, but don't mix a 2012 binary with 2015; you'll end up mixing CRTs

Comment: hm, I will try to build the lib from source

Comment: I added more information. Note that I not used with compiler options on visual studio. I just followed the tutorial on http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-vc.php

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when trying to compile a SFML program with SFML for VS2013 when using VS2015. Downloading (and obviously using) the correct version solved the problem.